# How do i modify objects in Excel COM using powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell, com, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm just creating a simple script to change the Excel `odbcconnections.connection` value and it throws an error. Is there some special way to set/create objects when using COM?

```
$xlsx = "C:\Users\blah.xlsx"
 $Excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
 $ExcelWorkbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($xlsx) 
 $conn = $ExcelWorkbook.Connections
 $blah= 'string'
 $DebugPreference="Continue"

 foreach($con in $conn)
 {


    write-debug  ($con.ODBCConnection.Connection)

    $con.ODBCConnection.connection = "newString"

    write-debug  ($con.ODBCConnection.Connection)

 }

 $Excel.workbooks.close()
 spps -n excel
```

This is the error I get:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC At line:19 char:5 +
>   $con.ODBCConnection.connection = "newString ... +
>
> ```
> CategoryInfo : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException +
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
> ```

Comment: I'm guessing a sample connection string would be helpful in reproducing the error.

Comment: It give same error whether i use a string or variable to assign a value.

Comment: DSN=nav2019;Description=Navision Live;UID=jsmith;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=2007 Microsoft Office system;WSID=HP-73012145W;DATABASE=JWBCBCC1308

Comment: I see Microsoft Office 2007 in your connection string. Does the data from the connection exceed 65K rows? i.e. Excel 2007/Compatibility view limit?

Comment: No, the original purpose is to change the database listed in the connection string for excel docs/reports that already exist. The data is already valid, just switching database/odbc connection the excel doc uses to access it.

Comment: My advice is always the same in these situations...and maybe you've already done it...but write the equivalent code in VBA and try to run it as a macro in Excel first. Make sure it works there and then port it to PowerShell or whatever COM compatible language you want.

Comment: I've written next to nothing in VBA, any tips to start? when you say "port it" you can literally copy-paste snippets into powershell?